# How can i modify my regular expression to not to remove new line

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am using this expression in my code to remove blank spaces in a string.

```
var TestString= some string with blank spaces and/or new lines;
TestString=TestString.replace(/^\&nbsp\;|<br?\>*/gi, '').replace(/\&nbsp\;|<br?\>$/gi, '').trim();
```

Now this Regular expression removes a new line also.what i need is it should remove spaces at start at end but not when enter is pressed that is when new line is created.

Any idea how do i modify this expression to achieve that?

Edit after some research:

```
TestString=TestString.replace(/&[^;]+;/g, '').replace(/<br\s*\/?>/mg,'\n');
```

If i use this expression it shows them with new line but after uploading it doesn't show them as that.Any idea why is it so?
Is it not possible to make a new line in editable table td element?

Comment: How does your TestString look? How do you define newlines? `<br />` pretty much makes a newline by breaking the current one.

Comment: @Allan Actually i am uploading a string to a url and before that i need to remove the spaces.It's a editable html text box so suppose if the string is "    test String    " then it gets converted to "test string" with my expression but if i press enter and write some thing in a new line then it's ignoring new line.For example if after first line i press enter and write "test string in second line" then it shows them all together as "test stringtest string in second line".But i need them to be "test String" and then in second line "test string in second line"

Comment: @allan if i enter "test1 line1" for the first line,"test2 line 2" for the second line then the string looks like test1 line1<br>test2 line2

Answer (score 0):

Does adding multiline mode "m" to "/gi" works ?

Comment: can you please elaborate what you meant by that answer?